# How can you detect if SKShapeNode is touched?

Tags: sprite-kit, sknode, skshapenode

I created a sknodeshape.  How can I detect if the shape I made was touched(clicked)?

Here is the code: (I solved it already)

```
//metung_babi is the name of the SKShapeNode

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint nokarin = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:nokarin];

if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"metung_babi"]) {
    NSlog(@"touch me not");
}
```

my mistake was when I created the shape I put the SKShapeNode name before initializing it.

Comment: the actual shape (path) or its frame?

Answer (score 2):

Implement the touch delegate methods. Then, in the -touchesBegan: method, extract the point of touch and retrieve the node using the [self nodeAtPoint:] method

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    SKNode *yourNode = ....;
    CGRect yourNodeFrame = bowlNode.frame;

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(yourNodeFrame, location)) {

        //your node may be touched, check if it's your node
        SKNode *theNode = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

        if ([theNode.name isEqualTo:yourNode.name]) {
            //it's your node touched
        }
    }
}
```

the method `nodeAtPoint` return value is complicated. you can check the document to find different situations

Comment: your solution is definitely wrong. Anyway just use my code it is much simpler.